# ASP code not working Request.Form("contact")("email")

Tags: asp-classic, vbscript

Below is my code where `Request.Form("contact")("email")` is associative array please help me.

```
If NOT Request.Form("type") = Null and Trim(Request.Form("type"))="unsubscribe" Then
    emailaddress=Trim(Request.Form("contact")("email")) 'this need to sure 
Else
    emailaddress=""
End If
```

The PHP equivalent would be:

```php
$emailaddress=$_POST["contact"]["email"];
```

Basically, I'm looking for something like this (pseudo-code):

```php
 [contact] => Array ( [id] => 50984 [email] => test1@test.com [first_name] => test [last_name] => test [ip] => 127.0.0.1 )
```

Comment: Could you describe what you mean by "not working"?

Comment: Basically I am not sure about it I know PHP. PHP equivalent code is $emailaddress=$_POST["contact"]["email"]; BUT I NEED same code in ASP

Comment: I removed my answer below; I didn't initially realize what you meant by associative array; your comment above line-breaked before the `["email"]` part, so... anyway; ASP doesn't have something that works exactly like that. You'd be best to change the HTML syntax of your form here.

Comment: @ Andrew Barber one dimensional is OK...basically the array is return by activecampaign api...they code example in php but i need to convert it in ASP.

Comment: @ Andrew Barber [contact] => Array
        (
            [id] => 50984
            [email] => test1@test.com
            [first_name] => test
            [last_name] => test
            [ip] => 127.0.0.1
        ) pass by post method which I need to assign value in asp by post method

Comment: Cool; Just to be sure, are you able to change the HTML `name` attributes of the fields? So instead of `name="contact[email]` you could use `name="email"`? I'm editing my answer on that assumption now...

Comment: Just FYI; I've edited and restored my answer; see if that's what you are looking for.

Comment: Okay; deleted again, since my assumption above was not correct... I've never tried it, but I think in ASP you can simply literally use the full name of the field as the value inside `Request.Form`. So, `Request.Form("contact[email]")`

Comment: Request.Form("contact[email]") it's Work Great

Comment: @AndrewBarber worth editing and undeleting your answer with this... :)

Comment: @ShadowWizard Yup; thanks for the reminder. Done!

Comment: @Andrew my pleasure, +1 and slight fix. :)